# read only li tag and not everything else below in the DOM tree?

Tags: jquery, list, dom, each

I have this list items:

```
<li class="list">A <span class="kol">1</span></li>
<li class="list">B <span class="kol">1</span></li>
<li class="list">C <span class="kol">1</span></li>
```

I'm using this to read the values:

```
$( ".list" ).each(function() {
    alert($(this).text()); //gives me A 1
    alert($(this).children().text()); //gives me 1
});
```

I need to be able to get only `A` value in the first alert. How can I do that? Is there any jQuery method for that so it doesn't read everything below `li` tag in a DOM tree?

Comment: it's not exactly duplicate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure of a direct way but this is something

```
$(".list").each(function () {
    console.log($(this).clone().find('span').remove().end().text()); //gives me A
    console.log($(this).children().text()); //gives me 1
});
```

Comment: just what I needed...haven't use˙`clone` before so thumb up for that! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

[.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

```
console.log($(this).clone().children('span').remove().end().text());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could grab the first `nodeValue` from each `li.list's` `childNodes`:

```
console.log(this.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vSr3b/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the firstChild with data

```
$(".list").each(function(i, item) {
    alert(item.firstChild.data); 
});
```